# Parsing file and detection of pattern in Java

Tags: java, csv, pattern-matching, string-parsing

My problem is quite simple, ***i am parsing a CSV file, line after line*** and i want to get the values of the columns.
The separators used are simply "`;`", but my file can have quite a lot of columns, and they won't be always in the same order.

So as example for my .CSV file :

```
time;columnA;columnB,ColumnC
27-08-2013 14:43:00; this is a text; this too; same here
```

And **i would like to be able to get all the values of time, columnA, columnB and columnC.
What would be the easiest way?**

I used `StringUtils.countMatches(input, ";");` to get the number of separators i have.
I started trying to make a `String index[][] = {{"time", "columnA", "columnB", "columnC"}{}};`
And my plan was to fill this with the number of "`;`" before each other variable, so that i could easily now which result stands for which variable.

But now i'm quite stuck...

If you want me to show more of my code, i can.
Hope that someone can help me ! :)

(sorry for the poor english).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410538/which-is-the-best-csv-parser-in-java

Comment: There is a library for parsing csv files : OpenCSV. Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `split()` method

For instance:

```
Scanner aScanner = ...
ArrayList<String> L = new ArrayList<String>();
while(aScanner.hasNextLine()){
    L.add(aScanner.nextLine());
}
int rows = L.size();
String[][] S = new String[rows][];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    S[i] = L.get(i).split(";");
}
```

Comment: The name if the class where the `split` method is found and a short example would have motivated me to upvote. The way it is tates to a comment.

Comment: Hmmm... i'm not sure i really get it, so with split i should just simply cut the different parts of my input?
But i read the file line after line :/ isn't it a problem?
(I'm gonna try your idea)

Comment: First, read the lines and add them to an ArrayList.Next, split the lines in order.

Comment: Okey, i did'nt understood your example, but i figured out how to use split ! Thanks a lot :D