# Printing a bidimensional array (generated with split) in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

So solved [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466021/parsing-file-and-detection-of-pattern-in-java) but now, after I figured out how to split my String into an array, I want this array to be bi-dimensional.
And when I want to print the second dimension I receive

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17
at IOControl.ReadCsvFile.fillIndex(ReadCsvFile.java:17)
at IOControl.ReadCsvFile.<init>(ReadCsvFile.java:89)
at en.window.Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

I figured out it's because i'm reading too far in my array... but why?
My array-declaration :

```
        String index[][] = new String [data.length()][data.length()];
```

This is how i fill & print the bidimensionnal array :

```
private void fillIndex(String[][] index, String data, int j)
{
    //index is empty, data is my String (read line by line)
    //j is the iterator i use for the second dimension of the array
    index[j] = data.split(";");
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("[" +j+ "][" +i+ "] = " +index[j][i]);           
    }
}
```

Comment: `data.length()` returns the length of the String `data`.

Comment: It is possible that j has a valid greater or equal to data.length. Could you give us the arguments you're passing when you get the exception?

Comment: shouldn't you be looping over index[j].length instead of data.length()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `index[j].length` instead of `data.length()`.

The number of items is `index[j].length = data.split(";").length`

Comment: Oo You are right ! Thanks for the fast and correct answer,
But what did i exactly done wrong?
I thought the length of the string in my array would be the same as my string :/

Comment: data.length() is the number of the characters but index[j].length is the number of the string after split()

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it is in the for loop, try changing it to this:

```
index[j] = data.split(";");
for(int i = 0; i < index[j].length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("[" +j+ "][" +i+ "] = " +index[j][i]);           
}
```

You want to iterate through each part of `index[j]` NOT `data`.

Comment: **.length()** is only for String object , for array it is **.length**

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Thanks, copy and paste mistake.